# tiptap - Insert node below / at the end of the current one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tiptap, prose-mirror

I'm trying to create a text editor with [tiptap](https://tiptap.dev) using reactjs. I would like to create a button next to each "block" of the editor (`paragraph` block, `blockquote` block, `codeblock` block, ...) that allows the user to add a new empty block just before the selected block. It would look like this (Notion editor) :

[image: Add block below current demo]

So the way I tried to do this is to set the cursor's position at the end of the current node :

```
src/components/blocks/Paragraph.js

const Paragraph = (props) => {
    // ...

    

    return {
        // ...
        <button onMouseDown={() => {
            // ...

            // props.getPos() gives the position at the beginning of the block
            // props.node.nodeSize gives the "length" of the node
            const endPos = props.getPos() + props.node.nodeSize;
            props.editor.commands.focus(endPos);

            // ...
        }}>
             Add block below
        </button>
    }
}
```

So at this point, it works. But then, when I try to insert a new `node` at this position...

```
// It will insert a paragraph node containing text "New block added"
props.editor.commands.insertContent({
    "type":"paragraph",
    "content":[
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"New block added"
        }
    ]
})
```

... I get an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null`

So, to let you see this error in details, I've made a sandbox on codesandbox.io. To reproduce the error, you just have to focus on the editor, write something random and then click on `+` button. You should see the error.

[image: Error when adding a new block]

[image: Edit react-passing-local-state-to-parent-component]

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Where are `props.getPos` and `props.node` defined?

Comment: I edited my post but you can see the full code inside the sandbox

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Current solution

---

**Currently** the best solution I've found :

```
// Last position of the current node (props are available in a react node view: https://tiptap.dev/guide/node-views/react#all-available-props)
const endPos = props.getPos() + props.node.nodeSize

// I focus the start of the editor because
// when the cursor is at the end of the node below which 
// we want to add a block, it doesn't focus the next block
props.editor.commands.focus('start')

props.editor
    .chain()
    .insertContentAt(endPos, {type: "paragraph"})
    .focus(endPos)
    .run()
```

Comment: I was able to get this work with `editor.chain().focus('end').insertContent().run()` so didn't need to get the endPos value.

Comment: @sirclesam Your code will add content at the end of the editor, not at the end of the current node. Well it's true that I didn't mention what was `endPos`, I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: ah yes - My use case is to insert at the end of the editor.  Thanks for the clairfication.